# How to properly use google signIn with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, google-signin

When I'm trying to sign in and on the next view sign out with GIDSignIn and navigate to previous view everything is fine, but when I'm trying to sign in again, the alert ask *App wants to use google sign in*, when I press continue - I have an error says:

**Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present )**

and the next error

**First responder error: non-key window attempting reload - allowing due to manual keyboard (first responder window is >, key window is ; layer = >)**

My code

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn

struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                Button(action: SocialLogin().attemptLoginGoogle, label: {
                    HStack{
                        Image("google")
                        Text("Google login")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                })
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16))
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8.0)
                        .shadow(radius: 4.0)

                NavigationLink(destination: UserData(), isActive: self.$loginViewModel.isLogedIn) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
        }

    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}

struct SocialLogin: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) {
    }

    func attemptLoginGoogle() {

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that until Google release pure SwiftUI version of their GIDSignIn it is better to use it in separated pure UIKit window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was in

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
```

You have to present in ViewController (in my case UIRepresentableViewController worked) otherwise it will tell you that keyboard can't show or present new View

Wrapper:

```
struct WrapedViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> LoginViewController {
        let vc =  LoginViewController()
        print("\nmakeUIViewController \(vc)")
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: LoginViewController, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIViewController \(uiViewController)")
    }

    static func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: LoginViewController, coordinator: Self.Coordinator) {
        print("dismantleUIViewController \(uiViewController)")
    }
}
```

Wraped ViewController:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height

        let height: CGFloat = 40.0
        let width: CGFloat  = 120.0

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (screenWidth / 2.0) - (width / 2.0),
                                            y: (screenHeight / 2.0) - (height / 2.0),
                                            width: width,
                                            height: height))

        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is I just know how to code in swiftUI. so I dont know how to use UIViewController

Comment: got same problem. Any solutions in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 8):

I encounter this problem in SwiftUI.

and I use this code.

```
      if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController==nil){
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
      }
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
```

Answer (score 5):

change

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
```

to

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
```